# Find the characteristic function of an experiment (random variable) involving a bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning, characteristic-functions, bernoulli-distribution

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. I flip coin with distribution $U \sim Bernoulli(p)$. Consider the following random variable:
$$
M=\begin{cases}
   X, & \text{if $U = 1$}\\
            Y, & \text{if $U = 0$}
   \end{cases}
$$

I would like to calculate the characteristic function of $M$:
$$\varphi_M(s) = E\left[ e^{i s M}  \right]$$
Note that $M$ is $X$ with probability $p$ and $Y$ wih probability $q = 1- p$. So, my first attempt is to do:
$$\varphi_M(s) = E\left[ e^{i s M}  \right]= e^{isX}p + e^{isY}q$$
But I think that this is wrong!

Can you help me?

**Update**

My intiuition says that

$$\varphi_M(s) = p \varphi_X(s) + q \varphi_Y(s)$$

where $\varphi_X(s)$ and $\varphi_Y(s)$ a, respectively, the ch. f. of $X$ and $Y$, but I don't know how to show whether this is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing $U$ is independant of $X$ and $Y$ we have :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi_M(s)&=&\mathbb E[e^{isM}(\mathbb 1_{U=1}+\mathbb 1_{U=0})]\\
&=&\mathbb E[e^{isM}\mathbb 1_{U=1}]+\mathbb E[e^{isM}\mathbb 1_{U=0}]\\
&=&\mathbb E[e^{isX}\mathbb 1_{U=1}]+\mathbb E[e^{isY}\mathbb 1_{U=0}]\\
&=&\mathbb E[e^{isX}]\mathbb E[\mathbb 1_{U=1}]+E[e^{isY}]\mathbb E[\mathbb 1_{U=0}]\\
&=&\varphi_X(s)\mathbb P(U=1)+\varphi_Y(s)\mathbb P(U=0)\\`&=&p\varphi_X(s)+q\varphi_Y(s)
\end{eqnarray*}